# Need a little help with this problem to do with partial derivatives?

Tags: calculus

Suppose $z = \ln\Big(\frac{x^3+y^3}{x-y}\Big)$. Show that $x\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+y \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=2.$ Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the partial derivatives using the chain and quotient rules:
$$ \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac{3x^2(x-y)-(x^3+y^3)}{(x-y)^2} \cdot \frac{(x-y)}{x^3+y^3} $$
$$ \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = \frac{3y^2(x-y)-(x^3+y^3)(-1)}{(x-y)^2} \cdot \frac{(x-y)}{x^3+y^3} $$
Now all you have to do is to simplify $x\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+y \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$ with the above expressions inserted and you will get the desired result of 2.

Answer (score 0):

I might be able to make this simpler.  Start by rewriting $z$ as

$$z=\ln(x^3+y^3)-\ln(x-y)$$
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{3x^2}{x^3+y^3}-\frac1{x-y}$$
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=\frac{3y^2}{x^3+y^3}+\frac1{x-y}$$
Now the calculation should be a lot easier.